# how to pass data between to controllers in asp.net mvc?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, session, cookies

I'm trying to pass data between controllers using TempData, when I run my project I get below error:

> ```
>  The SessionStateTempDataProvider class requires session state to be enabled.
>     Description: An unhandled exception occurred during the execution of the current web request. Please review the stack trace
> ```
>
> for more information about the error and where it originated in the
>   code.
>
> ```
>     Exception Details: System.InvalidOperationException: The SessionStateTempDataProvider class requires session state to be
> ```
>
> enabled

here is my web.config:

```
  <system.web>
    <customErrors mode="Off">
      <error statusCode="404" redirect="~/View/Shared/NotFountError"/>
      <error statusCode="500" redirect="~/View/Shared/InternalServerError"/>
    </customErrors>
    <authentication mode="None"/>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.6.2"/>
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5"/>
  <sessionState mode="InProc" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <staticContent>
      <clientCache cacheControlMode="UseMaxAge" cacheControlMaxAge="10.00:00:00"/>
    </staticContent>
    <httpProtocol>
      <customHeaders>
        <remove name="Vary"/>
        <add name="Vary" value="Accept-Encoding"/>
      </customHeaders>
    </httpProtocol>
    <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">
      <remove name="FormsAuthenticationModule"/>
      <add name="SA.Filter.Filter" type="SA.Filter.Filter"/>
    </modules>
    <handlers>
      <remove name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0"/>
      <remove name="OPTIONSVerbHandler"/>
      <remove name="TRACEVerbHandler"/>
      <add name="ExtensionlessUrlHandler-Integrated-4.0" path="*." verb="*" type="System.Web.Handlers.TransferRequestHandler" preCondition="integratedMode,runtimeVersionv4.0"/>
    </handlers>
    <directoryBrowse enabled="true"/>
  </system.webServer>
```

Comment: Try adding `<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">` under the modules node in the web.config

Comment: @too_cool i add it but still get same error i add error detail to question

Comment: Have you got `ASP.NET State Service` service running on your machine?

Comment: @Wurd yes , it's running.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like the server you're trying to run the application on doesn't have the Session State enabled by default.

You can enable this on a per application basis through your `web.config`, simply place this in the file:

```
<system.web>
    ..
    <sessionState mode="InProc" />
</system.web>
```

This will enable the default in process method of storing session state (server side).

If that doesn't help, it could point to another issue but we'd need to see the full exception information & stack trace.

Comment: i add it but still get same error i add error detail to question

Comment: @AhmadGhasemi We need the stack trace to diagnose further. If you could post your web.config that would also be useful.

Comment: I add a part of web.config.

Answer (score 0):

```
Google Solved: I added this attribute to the modules node in the web.config and EVERYTHING magically started working:

<modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true">

It looks like I'm not alone:
Some sample Links are below for your reference.

http://forums.asp.net/p/1293974/2509190.aspx

http://www.flyvergrillen.dk/2009/03/26/being-trapped-in-iis/

I think my pure MVC project (that worked in Test environment) was too simple and may not have forced the MVC framework to require TempData and SessionState, so that's how I'll explain it away ;-)
```

Comment: I see first link add `      <add name="UrlRoutingModule" type="System.Web.Routing.UrlRoutingModule, System.Web.Routing, Version=0.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31BF3856AD364E35"/>
` . but did not help me.

Comment: what is secont link ?